# Does tipping happen at the highest level?

Tags: tournament

In tournaments like High Stakes Poker and the World Series of Poker, are the players tipping?  Would it be at the same rate as most tipping seen in casinos?  If it does happen, doesn't it affect chip counts?

Comment: You would never tip a chip as the chips themselves do not have cash value.  What gets cashed is the position you finish.

Comment: The chips in a tournament have NO CASH value.  Player is not even allowed to take them from the table.  They are bagged and tagged.

Comment: The question specifically states tournament. A dealer cannot convert a tournament chip to cash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tipping in tournaments occurs after the prizes have been paid out. There is no tipping during a hand. Typically the winner, and perhaps some of the other top finishers will tip a portion of their winnings, to be distributed to the dealers.

See this question on [tipping when I cash a live tournament](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/9853/how-much-should-i-be-tipping-when-i-cash-a-live-tournament?rq=1) for further information how much to tip.

Answer (score 3):

So as Herb posted another question that answers this for tournaments, I also want to include my experience of dealing cash games at the upper stakes as an addition to the above. For these examples, I am exclusively using the times I've dealt in the WSOP. I will also preface this as entirely my own experience, but I mostly stuck to cash games and satellites when I did work the WSOP, as I often had more fun doing these kind of games.

Cash games, I'm going to break it down into different limits because the tipping really varies across them, but in the mid limits is pretty consistent on the tipping and also the type of players matter here.

The highest I've dealt was 100$SB-200$BB, typically full of pros and rich amateurs, at this level the pros have a stack of 5$ chips for tipping, typically you'll get a 5$ chip a hand that goes to the flop or had significant action pre-flop. The rich players having fun can be a rollercoaster for tipping, if they're serious they'll tend to follow the pros, but if they're just splashing around it can really change. I've been tipped a 1k$ chip once. These players as a dealer are the best to have, they're fun, they just want to play, and often they can tip big. Generally though they'll often tip like 25$ if they win a pot.

Upper/middle stakes but not like the above, i.e. max like 50$bb, maybe a bit more will be fairly consistent with their tipping. Like the above with the pros, a stack of 5$s will be for tipping. Personally as a player I enjoyed these games, I learnt a lot sitting there watching them, as a dealer making a living off tips, no thanks. These are the grinder players who are doing well but, and especially at limits like 10$ or 25$, aren't going to be tipping big. It's pretty consistent a 5$ tip for making it to the river. Some players differ but it'll average out at 5$.

Low stakes, i.e. your 1-3 or 2-5 or 5-10 games are often a dollar tip every hand, especially the lower ones. Some players will give you up to 5$, but it's often 1$ or 2$. Interestingly enough these lower games, and in particular the 5-10 games can end up being big tip games, because they're affordable stakes, so you get people who come down to play for the weekend, are having a great time and you as a dealer, if you help them have a great time they can and do tip big, maybe 25$. You get a lot of players here that will promise you X$ tip if they win the hand, and often they deliver on that figure (from my experience).

Comment: The question specifically asks about tournament (not cash).